# PHP - what is filter_id() used for?

Tags: php

What is the usage of filter_id() in php is that just an integer?

for example:

```
echo(filter_id("validate_email"));
```

it just return an integer. i search a lot(i mean not really) and i cant find any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [filter functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php) using filter ids to validate (filter) variables. For example [filter_var](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function:

```
<?php

$filterId = filter_id('validate_email');

$isEmail = filter_var('user@example.com', $filterId);
var_dump($isEmail); // output: user@example.com

$isNotEmail = filter_var('some text', $filterId);
var_dump($isNotEmail); // output: false
```

Comment: You always should use id for filter functions, as they are expecting filter id (int) as input. And to get filter id `filter_id` function or `FILTER_` constants are used.