# Is filter_id() supposed to be an integer or a string in PHP?

Tags: php, filter, php-7

This is a follow up question to [PHP - what is filter_id() used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60364919/3429430)

If I try something like `echo filter_id('validate_email')`, I get `274`, but I expect it to give `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` as mentioned at https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php. I don't understand what these numbers like `257, 258, 520, 521, 1024` represent? Why do we have two values(numeric and string) of filter_id for each type of filter?

Comment: `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` is __constant name__, `274` is __constant value__.

Comment: @u_mulder What's the point of having these `CONST` constants available in global php space?

Comment: As of any other constants - to use named and understandable value instead of some `274`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood the CONSTANT name refers to the integer value. The string name is just something that makes it more readable for us programmers.

The integer numbers are used as bits (on/off) for the filter string. Using a Bitwise operation the engine checks its flags to see if a validation needs to checked or not. This can be seen in the code of PHP like on https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/filter/logical_filters.c.

The actual part where you can see that the CONSTANT name is mapped to the CONSTANT value using a define is in the file filter_private.h https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/f13d0a72d5cf92785c91ffc33c27df3df3f8e96e/ext/filter/filter_private.h#L64.